# Default MkMapView Region

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

Please tell me what is the default map location when it simply add to the view.
I added mapview like this

```
MKMapView *mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,  self.searchBar.frame.size.height, 320, 180)];

mapView.mapType=MKMapTypeStandard;

mapView.delegate=self; 

[self.view addSubview:mapView];
```

what location will show on map ?

Is this according to device coordinates or by other

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After done so googling and reading apple map doc.

I found the solution the default location is the device local that is International in Settings -> general ->International->ResionFormat-> select your country.

map will focus according to this setting.

Answer (score 2):

I think the system makes a call and Apple's servers return this info.

I've made a little test with simulator (Extra info: I'm in Spain):

- **Test 1**

  1. Turn off internet access
  2. iOS simulator > Reset content and settings
  3. Build and run app w/mapview
  4. Turn on internet access
  5. Little scroll on map (just for change region a little and begin with map tiles downloading)
  6. **United states** is being displayed on screen

     ---
- **Test 2 (wihtout turning off internet)**

  1. iOS simulator > Reset content and settings
  2. Build and run app w/mapview
  3. **Spain** is being displayed on screen

     ---

I don't think that Apple's getting user location without consent. It could be a request for default location IP based as a part of operative system.

Comment: it's a really interesting issue - I too cannot, really, find what formula they use for the "true initial map, for that user"

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's lat/long 0, 0 which is somewhere in the ocean above Africa. You see this as a bug in a surprising number of apps which don't set the lat long and you end up seeing a map showing just blue - the sea.

Suggest you just test it!

Answer (score 0):

No answer seems to be correct, at least with iOS8. Apple does not provide documented information on the default region of a mapView, but I believe that MapKit makes a request to the Apple server to get the current country code. In fact, if you try to turn off Internet connection and open a viewcontroller with a simple map just allocated and added as subview to the main view, the debugger will display this message:

**Could not determinates current country code: Error Domain = GEOErrorDomain Code = 2 "The operation could not be completed. (GEOErrorDomain error -2.)**

There's something unknown that gets the current country code and shows that country as initial region in a mapview. This "current country code" is not related with the user location, as the message is also shown by disabling location services (unless Apple takes the user's location without user authorization, which is impossible). Maybe it uses the IP address of the Internet connection to make  IP tracert. I will try to use a proxy to verify.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

> mapViewWillStartLoadingMap

delegate method in which you can customize the location coordinates as below,

NOTE: This need no location permission check or authorization.

```
func mapViewWillStartLoadingMap(_ mapView: MKMapView) {

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 46.7111, longitude: 1.7191)

        let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 100_000

        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, latitudinalMeters: regionRadius * 2.0, longitudinalMeters: regionRadius * 2.0)

        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: The question isn't asking how to set an initial region. The question is asking what the initial region will be by default.